# Set the price for gift option in magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, gift-card, gift-wrap

I want to set the price for particular gift option like the gift-card message on checkout page..how to do it please provide the proper way to set the price  for gift-message

Answer (score 0):

Example code of adding Gift Wrapping price

Create file `app/etc/modules/Inchoo_GiftWrapping.xml` with the following content:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_GiftWrapping>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Enterprise_GiftWrapping/>
            </depends>
        </Inchoo_GiftWrapping>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create configuration file app/code/local/Inchoo/GiftWrapping/etc/config.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Inchoo_GiftWrapping>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Inchoo_GiftWrapping>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <enterprise_giftwrapping>
                <rewrite>
                    <total_quote_giftwrapping>Inchoo_GiftWrapping_Model_Total_Quote_Giftwrapping</total_quote_giftwrapping>
                </rewrite>
            </enterprise_giftwrapping>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <inchoo_giftwrapping>
                <class>Inchoo_GiftWrapping_Helper</class>
            </inchoo_giftwrapping>
        </helpers>
    </global>
 </config>
```

> Important and useful step

Create file `app/code/local/Inchoo/GiftWrapping/etc/system.xml` with the following content:

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <sales>
            <groups>
                <gift_options>
                    <fields>
                        <free_gift_wrapping_price translate="label" module="inchoo_giftwrapping">
                            <label>Charge for Gift Wrap Service if the basket value is under</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>15</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                        </free_gift_wrapping_price>
                    </fields>
                </gift_options>
            </groups>
        </sales>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Note that now you can see in Magento administration under System/Configuration/Sales/Sales/Gift Options tab new input field where you can specify desired amount for: **“Charge for Gift Wrap Service if the basket value is under“**.

**Rewrite Model**
Create file `app/code/local/Inchoo/GiftWrapping/Model/Total/Quote/Giftwrapping.php` with the following content:

```
<?php

/**
 * GiftWrapping total calculator for quote
 * @category    Inchoo
 * @package     Inchoo_GiftWrapping
 * @author      Ivan Galambos <ivan.galambos@inchoo.net>
 */
class Inchoo_GiftWrapping_Model_Total_Quote_Giftwrapping extends Enterprise_GiftWrapping_Model_Total_Quote_Giftwrapping
{
    /**
     * Collect wrapping total for quote
     *
     * @param   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     * @return  Enterprise_GiftWrapping_Model_Total_Quote_Giftwrapping
     */
    protected function _collectWrappingForQuote($address)
    {
        $wrappingBasePrice = false;
        $wrappingPrice = false;

        //include price if !canuseFreeGiftWrapping
        if ( !(Mage::helper('inchoo_giftwrapping')->canUseFreeGiftWrapping()) ) {
            if ($this->_quoteEntity->getGwId()) {
                $wrapping = $this->_getWrapping($this->_quoteEntity->getGwId(), $this->_store);
                $wrappingBasePrice = $wrapping->getBasePrice();
                $wrappingPrice = $this->_store->convertPrice($wrappingBasePrice);
            }
        }

        $address->setGwBasePrice($wrappingBasePrice);
        $address->setGwPrice($wrappingPrice);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Collect printed card total for quote
     *
     * @param   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
     * @return  Inchoo_GiftWrapping_Model_Total_Quote_Giftwrapping
     */
    protected function _collectPrintedCard($address)
    {
        $printedCardBasePrice = false;
        $printedCardPrice = false;

        //include price if !canuseFreeGiftWrapping
        if ( !(Mage::helper('inchoo_giftwrapping')->canUseFreeGiftWrapping()) ) {
            if ($this->_quoteEntity->getGwAddCard()) {
                $printedCardBasePrice = Mage::helper('enterprise_giftwrapping')->getPrintedCardPrice($this->_store);
                $printedCardPrice = $this->_store->convertPrice($printedCardBasePrice);
            }
        }

        $address->setGwCardBasePrice($printedCardBasePrice);
        $address->setGwCardPrice($printedCardPrice);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Create Helper Class file `app/code/local/Inchoo/GiftWrapping/Helper/Data.php` with the following content:

```
<?php

/**
 * GiftWrapping helper data
 *
 * @category    Inchoo
 * @package     Inchoo_GiftWrapping
 * @author      Ivan Galamboš <ivan.galambos@inchoo.net>
 */
class Inchoo_GiftWrapping_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Min. base price to get free GiftWrapping Service
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    public $_baseFreePrice = null;

    /**
     * can use free Gift Wrapping service
     *
     * @var mixed
     */
    public $freeGiftWrapping = null;

    /**
     * Return limit as base price for free Gift Wrapping Service
     *
     * @return flaot
     */
    public function getBasePriceForFreeGiftWrappingService()
    {
        if (empty($this->_baseFreePrice)) {
            $this->_baseFreePrice = (float)Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/gift_options/free_gift_wrapping_price');
        }

        return $this->_baseFreePrice;
    }

    /**
     * Can show free Gift Wrapping Service on frontend
     * Basket value must be grater or equal to set price for Free Gift Wrapping Service
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canUseFreeGiftWrapping()
    {
        if (!is_bool($this->freeGiftWrapping)) {

            $baseFreeGift = $this->getBasePriceForFreeGiftWrappingService();
            $baseTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBaseGrandTotal();

            if ( $baseTotal >= $baseFreeGift ) {
                $this->freeGiftWrapping = true;
            } else {
                $this->freeGiftWrapping = false;
            }

        }

        return $this->freeGiftWrapping;

    }
}
```

**Front-end modifications**
For example you can open file: `app/design/frontend/enterprise/[YOUR_THEME]/template/giftwrapping/checkout/options.phtml`and add 2 modifications (you don’t want to change core file – if you don’t have one please copy one):

1) in gift-wrapping-container area you can replace with:

```
<span class="regular-price">
                        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?>:</span>
                        <?php if (Mage::helper('inchoo_giftwrapping')->canUseFreeGiftWrapping()):?>
                            <span class="price"><?php echo $this->__('Free') ?></span>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <span class="price" id="regular-price-{{id}}"></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
</span>
```

and 2) in gift-options-container area you can replace with:

```
<span class="regular-price">
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?>:</span>
                    <span class="price" id="regular-card-price-{{id}}">
                    <?php echo (Mage::helper('inchoo_giftwrapping')->canUseFreeGiftWrapping()) ? $this->__('Free') : '{{price}}'; ?></span>
</span>
```

Now your customers will see “Free” price instead of regular one on checkout page for Gift Wrapping service & Printed Card feature.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: after installing this module it shows me an error "Module "Inchoo_GiftWrapping" requires module "Enterprise_GiftWrapping"."